# Azure Log Analytics - Comparing Two message traces to raise an alert if one updates

Tags: azure, azure-functions, kql, azure-log-analytics

I have a Function App that pulls the Azure public key usng a PowerShell script and outputs it into log analytics. I am trying to get notified if the public key updates. At the moment, I am comparing the top two results to see changers.

Does anyone know a query that could compare two message outputs to see if the output value changers? This will be to create an alert and more automation if the public key does change.

[image: Image Example Here]

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, for example by using the [`next()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/nextfunction):

```
traces
| where message has "OUTPUT"
| top 2 by timestamp desc
| extend different = next(message) != message
| take 1
| where different == true
```

using `next()` you can lookup the value of a column of the next row. We can use that to compare with the current value of `message`.

Comment: Legend! Thanks heaps for this, looks like it's a working solution.

Comment: @MikeLove feel free to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was of any help to you so other know it has been answered.